# Is SHA-256 + Salt still safe for password storage?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, hash, sha256

I am developing a website which requires users to register to it in order to use it's functions and I was wondering if SHA-256 + salt (random salt provided by RNGCryptoServiceProvider  in C#) is secure and good enough to use in 2017?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The first post is from 2011 and the second one is from 2015. Security information changes.

Comment: It wasn't good in 2011, it hasn't magically become good since then.

Comment: Use PBKDF2, scrypt, or bcrypt. Anything else (including salted single-iteration SHA256) is unacceptable. End of story.

Comment: This is wrong. Argon2 is presumably the best answer now, but not the conservative one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For password storage, salted SHA256 hashes are *not* recommended. This is because the general purpose SHA256 is designed to be fast. Fast is exactly what you do not want for a password hashing algorithm, because it makes brute force and dictionary attacks far more efficient.

Password storage hashes are designed to require a certain workload and in some instances, a minimum memory requirement. Good password storage scheme are designed to be hard to serialize and/or optimize.

The recommended password storage scheme in 2017 is BCrypt hash, with PBKDF2 as alternative, but slightly less regarded, option.

For a more complete answer, please read the sec.se ['standard answer'](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/2113) on password hashing by [Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin).

Comment: While I agree with the answer in general, that there is no real way to protect bad passwords in your DB against a dictionary attack.

Comment: @Eiver You can't protect against the absolute worst passwords; but the difference between 10k tries/second/box and 10b tries/sec/box is enough to protect the average user who has a marginally strong password against non-targetted attacks.

Comment: Bitcoin is based on SHA-256. If a Bitcoin secret is so easy to be brute-forced because of the speed of SHA-256, it wouldn't have been chosen. Now, is a password more important than a Bitcoin secret to call for a slower algorithm to delay the brute-force? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

It could be - if it meets your risk assessment for the potential threats you feel it faces.

But I would recommend you look at using a Password Based Derivation Function. These are hashed based style functions ideal for password storage.

Look into PBKF#2 for your C# application. There is also the widely used Bcrypt (although I use the former with C# as it's native)

This maybe of help: https://lockmedown.com/hash-right-implementing-pbkdf2-net/

But I recommend you check the MSDN documentation for up to date information.